# Getting really weird Error messages when trying to do HitDetection on a UIBezierPath

Tags: ios, boolean, drawrect, cgcontext, uibezierpath

I have added this method to check if a `CGPoint` is inside a `UIBezierPath`

```
- (BOOL)isPointInPath:(CGPoint)point inShape:(BOOL)inShape {
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGPathRef cgPath = path.CGPath;

CGPathDrawingMode mode = kCGPathStroke;
if (inShape) mode = kCGPathFill;

CGContextSaveGState(context);
CGContextAddPath(context, cgPath);

bool isHit = CGContextPathContainsPoint(context, point, mode);
CGContextRestoreGState(context);

return isHit;
}
```

`path` is a `UIBezierPath` declared in the header file.

When I call this method outside the `drawRect:` method I get these 4 error messages:

```
CGContextSaveGState: invalid context 0x0
CGContextAddPath: invalid context 0x0
CGContextPathContainsPoint: invalid context 0x0
CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0
```

But when I call it inside the `drawRect:` and after the drawing it works.

Why doesn't it work outside the `drawRect:`? It makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is no current graphics context outside `drawRect:` (unless you create one), therefore
`context` is `NULL`.

But you don't need a graphics context to check if a point is inside the shape given
by a `UIBezierPath`, you can just use `containsPoint:` method.

Comment: I am getting same context error by calling somebezierpath.contains(somecgpoint).

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it myself, I realized `CGContext` was confusing to work with, so I used `CGPath` instead and used `CGPathContainsPoint` instead which worked.

Comment: Your question was about `UIBezierPath`, not `CGPath`, that's why I recommended `containsPoint:` in my answer.

Comment: Yea it was a great answer, but I found another way, I might delete the question.